# Reading content from file produces empty strings

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I am trying to read the content of a directory of files. Unfortunately, the data is not being read correctly (or at all, it seems). If I open these files independently, there is data, but when I try and examine the contents, the data is empty. The ultimate goal is to put all of the data into an array.

```
function readFilesSync(directory, filesInDirectory = []) {
  fs.readdirSync(directory)
    .forEach(file => {
        let content = fs.readFileSync(directory + file, 'utf8');
        console.log(content); // Blank
        const filepath = path.resolve(directory, file);
        const stat = fs.statSync(filepath);
        const isFile = stat.isFile();

        if (isFile) filesInDirectory.push(content);
    });
    return filesInDirectory;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I noticed I had a couple of typos. This is the var: let content = fs.readFileSync(dir + file, 'utf8');

Comment: Does this fix your issue?

Comment: I get `ReferenceError: dir is not defined`

Comment: @jmargolisvt No, still have the same issue.

Comment: dir + file is a *valid, existing, absolute* path?

Comment: @WilliamLohan Sorry, I fixed it.

Comment: @NurbolAlpysbayev Yes. I just verified. That's correct.

Comment: @Darnold14 What happens if you try to remove 'utf8' part? Also try this: `fs.readFileSync(directory + file).toString()`

Comment: Do you have any error and what does the directory look like?

Comment: @NurbolAlpysbayev Removing 'utf8' just prints [<Buffer>, <Buffer>, <Buffer>]

Comment: @Darnold14 This is good. Did you miss the `.toString()` part?

Comment: @NurbolAlpysbayev - no, toString prints [' ', ' ', ' ']

Comment: @Darnold14 and why it is an array, when in the demonstrated code it should be just a string? Are you showing as the actual code you have?

Comment: @Darnold14 Other than that, can you also show the exact value of `directory + file`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the error you are getting is

> EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read

then don't try to read directories

```
function readFilesSync(directory, filesInDirectory = []) {
    fs.readdirSync(directory)
        .forEach(file => {
            const filepath = path.resolve(directory, file);
            const stat = fs.statSync(filepath);
            const isFile = stat.isFile();

            if (isFile) {
                let content = fs.readFileSync(filepath, 'utf8');
                console.log(content); // Not Blank
                filesInDirectory.push(content);
            }
        });
    return filesInDirectory;
}
```

Comment: This is not my error. I am not getting any content of the file.

Comment: Well the code above works for me and I do get content, what does the dir look like?

Comment: So, the reason this wasn't working is because I was calling fs.open and it was erasing the contents in another function. But it works now.